# Equivalent function of Excel's TINV in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the equivalent function of Excel's TINV in Matlab.

TINV (in Excel) uses the probability and degree of freedom.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [`X = tinv(P,V)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tinv.html), but you have to have the Statistics Toolbox to use it.

Excel TINV computes the 2-sided distribution for `1-P`. MATLAB computes the 1-sided distribution for `P`. So for your example below, `tinv(0.95,700)` = 1.647.

As a sanity check, the table of tabulated values on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values) gives 1.645 for the limiting case of infinite degrees of freedom (normal distribution) for the 2-sided 90%/1-sided 95% inverse t-distribution.

Comment: I tried that. For example if P =0.1 and V = 700. You get -1.2828 in Matlab and 1.647033 in Excel.

Comment: Excel and MATLAB compute slightly different things. See the edit to get the equivalent answer.

Comment: So are you saying that i cannot get the exact value in Matlab directly?

Comment: No, I'm saying you need the correct inputs. The two functions will ultimately return the mathematically equivalent values as long as you understand what parameters you are putting in and what the answer coming out means. If `P_matlab = 1 - P_excel/2` you will **always** get the same result. Look at the text before and after the Wikipedia table for a discussion on the meaning of the two calculations.